# Silex framework, Backup Manager FileExistsException file already exists at path

Tags: symfony, silex

I used this script (https://github.com/backup-manager/backup-manager) on different website and works Well.
On a single one i have a problem : FileExistsException in Filesystem.php line 395:
File already exists at path: 5693d2350eb67test.sql.gz
(this is exactly the same code on each website)

I have implemented this script in a silex / Symfony application.
All My website is on the same Debian server.

Do you have any idea where to looking for ?
Maybe about server configuration, folder permission...

Thank you very much to help me. Sorry for my bad english ;)

This is the function I call :

```
 public function restoreAction($id, Application $app) {
    $manager = require 'BootstrapController.php';
    $sauvegarde =  $app['dao.sauvegarde']->findbyId($id);
    $nomfichier = $sauvegarde->getNomfichier();
    $nomfichiergz = $nomfichier.'.gz';
    $sauvegardesnext = $app['dao.sauvegarde']->findlaterthan($id);
    $manager->makeRestore()->run('local',$nomfichiergz, 'production', 'gzip');
    //On recrée le fichier de sauvegarde correspondant a la restauration effectuée
    //car ce putain de backupDB nous le supprime
    $manager->makeBackup()->run('production', 'local', $nomfichier, 'gzip');
    //On supprime le fichier sql temp

    //$urlfichier = $app['dossiersave'].$nomfichier;
    //$fs->remove($urlfichier);

    //On supprime de la bdd les sauvegardes qui n'ont plus de fichier save sur le disque
    //effectivement quand on fait la 2 ou + eme sauvegarde, celui ci mémorise les sauvegardes précedentes
    //mais si entre temps l'utilisateur les supprime, celle-ci ne devrait plus aparaitre 
    //elles sont pourtant ds le fichier savedb qu'on avait effectué avant car elle n'étaient pas supprimées a ce moment la !
    //
    $sauvegardes = $app['dao.sauvegarde']->findAll();
    foreach ($sauvegardes as $sauvegarde) {
        $fs = new Filesystem();
        if (($fs->exists($app['dossiersave'].$sauvegarde->getNomfichier().'.gz')) == false) {
            // On supprime la sauvegarde en bdd
            $app['dao.sauvegarde']->delete($sauvegarde->getId());
        }
    } 
    //On recrée les points de sauvegarde ulterieur a la restauration car elles ne sont 
    //plus en bdd
        foreach ($sauvegardesnext as $savedb) {
            $savecurrent = new Sauvegarde();
            //$savecurrent->setId($savedb->getId());
            $savecurrent->setDate($savedb->getDate());
            $savecurrent->setNom($savedb->getNom());
            $savecurrent->setNomfichier($savedb->getNomfichier());
            $app['dao.sauvegarde']->save($savecurrent);
        }

    $fs = new Filesystem();
    $fs->mirror($app['dossiersave'].'images'.$sauvegarde->getNom().'_'.$id,$app['dossierimages'],null,$options = array('delete' => true, 'override' => true ));


        $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Votre sauvegarde ' .$sauvegarde->getNom(). ' a bien été restaurée');
        return $app->redirect ('/admin');     
    }
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code

Comment: @mTorres thank u to have read my post , i have sent some code, if this can help u :)

Comment: Now you should follow the exception, and point which line of this code is throwing it, you've posted an exception on the Filesystem.php line 395, but this is due to your code calling it. From here you can try to figure out what's going on (the exception text is self explanatory though: you're trying to write a file that already exists).